# I'm having trouble getting a new window to open with Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

This is the error I'm getting when button to open new window is pressed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Jaguar/PycharmProjects/learnpython/chemcalc.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    Button(master, text='Sub', width=3, command=lambda: self.sub_win()).grid(row=2, column=6)
  File "/Users/Jaguar/PycharmProjects/learnpython/chemcalc.py", line 57, in sub_win
    top = Toplevel(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2336, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2286, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2256, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'calc' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import *


class calc:

    def sub_win(self):
        top = Toplevel(self)


    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title('Title')
        master.geometry()
        self.e = Entry(master, justify = RIGHT)
        self.e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=8, pady=3)
        self.answerlist = []

root = Tk()
obj=calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback). There are other useful info.Can you create `Toplevel` directly - without class?

Comment: BTW: you execute `calc()` but you don't have `__init__(self, parent)` and `Toplevel` uses `self` (which is not tkinter widget) but it need `root`.

Comment: I didn't post the full code, i have __init__(self, master)

Comment: Your code works. The error message does not correspond to the code you share.

Comment: The code should work, which is why I'm at such a loss. This error comes up button is pressed. I'm using a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `self` in `Toplevel(self)`

Most widgets need parent as first argument which have to be tkinter widget.

In your code `self` is not tkinter widget.
You have to use `master` as you did in `Entry(master)`

```
top = Toplevel(master)
```

but you will have to keep `master` as `self.master`.

`Toplevel` can also run without parent

```
top = Toplevel()
```

and it will use `Tk()` as parent.

Comment: The traceback suggests the error is inherent to a button press, IMHO it would be better to encourage the OP to share the code that corresponds to the actual error message.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ error message in question shows problem in `top = Toplevel(self)`. And there is corresponds code in question.